# Is it safe to reuse exception instances in Python?

Tags: python

In some cases, my code looks a lot cleaner if I create my exceptions up front, then raise them later:

```py
AUTHENTICATION_ERROR = HTTPException(
    status_code=fastapi.status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
    detail="Authentication failed",
    headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
)

# ...

async def current_user(token: str = Depends(oauth2_scheme)) -> User:
    """FastAPI dependency that returns the current user

    If the current user is not authenticated, raises an authentication error.
    """

    try:
        payload = jwt.decode(token, SECRET, algorithms=["HS256"])
    except JWTError:
        raise AUTHENTICATION_ERROR

    username = payload["sub"]

    if username not in stub_users:
        raise AUTHENTICATION_ERROR

    return stub_users[username]
```

However, I've never actually seen this done and it feels quite wrong. It appears to work though.

**In Python, is it *safe* to create Exception instances and raise them several times?**

(*Safe* meaning that it works as expected with no surprises)

Comment: Why would it not be?  Those are essentially read-only objects.

Comment: Yes.  As far as I can tell it is safe to reuse them.

Comment: @TimRoberts they are not, in fact, read-only. So, if this code is only going to be used internally, it's safe enough, but I wouldn't do it if this exception is going to be exposed to clients of this code. Instead, just wrap it in a fucntion, `def create_except(): return HTTPException()....`

Comment: @TimRoberts I thought perhaps Python does something to the Exception instance when you `raise` it, possibly making it unsafe in some contexts, such as multi-threading. For example, when you catch an exception, is that the same object as the one you raised? Has Python added any information to it, such as stack traces? How would this work if Python caught the exception in two threads simultaneously?

Comment: @Hubro Python itself won't do anything untoward, but there's no telling what consumers of this function might do. I would just wrap it in a function then use `raise create_http_exception()` myself. Maybe I'm just paranoid.

Comment: Oh, I'm pretty sure it won't work with multithreading.  That's a very different situation.  Somewhere in that object, the traceback info is stored, and that's going to be different for every use.

Comment: What about using classes and inheriting from `HttpException`. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#user-defined-exceptions. Should work with multithreading as well since it is its own kind of exception.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a custom exception and use it.

Makes the intention clear, is very "pythonic", and you could explicitly catch (the more specific) `AuthenticationError` in an outer function if needed.

```py
import fastapi
from fastapi.exceptions import HTTPException

class AuthenticationError(HTTPException):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(
            status_code=fastapi.status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail="Authentication failed",
            headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
       )

# ...

async def current_user(token: str = Depends(oauth2_scheme)) -> User:
    """FastAPI dependency that returns the current user

    If the current user is not authenticated, raises AuthenticationError.
    """

    try:
        payload = jwt.decode(token, SECRET, algorithms=["HS256"])
    except JWTError:
        raise AuthenticationError

    username = payload["sub"]

    if username not in stub_users:
        raise AuthenticationError

    return stub_users[username]
```